# List all files then execute script with part of the filename

Tags: server, bash, ssh, scp

I'm looking to list all files in a folder:

```
ABC123.cfg
XYZ456.cfg
EFG999.cfg
```

The file names, without the `.cfg` relate to a remote server name, `ABC123` etc.

I want to copy a couple of files to each of the remote servers.

So, look up the filenames, but take the name without the `.cfg`.  Then

```
scp filename.txt username@ABC123:/home/username/
```

For each remote server, overwriting the destination file if exists.

Each remote server uses the same username and password.
Can I use a password in the `scp` command?

Answer (score 4):

This should do the job:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.cfg; do
  sshpass -f /path/to/passwordfile scp ${i%.cfg}.txt username@${i%.cfg}:
done
```

or rather

```
for i in *.cfg;do sshpass -f /path/to/passwordfile scp ${i%.cfg}.txt username@${i%.cfg}:;done
```

The password is passed to `scp` using `sshpass` (following [How to pass password to scp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50096/how-to-pass-password-to-scp)) which reads it from `passwordfile` – remember to secure this file against unauthorized read access with `chmod 400`!

I got a little bit confused what file you want to send here, I understood there's e.g. a file `ABC123.txt` that has to be sent to host `ABC123`, so I just stripped `.cfg` using [Bash Parameter Expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) and added `.txt`.

As `user@host:` defaults to `user`'s home directory I removed the path.

Comment: AWESOME, thanks.  I was closer than I thought, but couldn't get it 100%.

Comment: Please, don't use `sshpass -p`. Even its [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass) notes that it's not very safe on most systems. Just use `SSHPASS=$password sshpass -e ...` instead.

Comment: @ilkkachu You're totally right, I changed the whole answer to suggest a much safer approach. Thank you!

Comment: Though you could spare the user the trouble of making a file, and ask them  for the password from the script and put in the envvar, something like `read -rs pass; SSHPASS=$pass sshpass -e ...` But then we're probably getting to the point where using ssh keys and `ssh-agent` would be smartest