# Permission denied when trying to run a script that uses 'sshpass'

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, ssh

The idea is to make this script run without needing to type any passwords of the hosts (written down in the `Hosts.txt` file). Right now, when I'm running this, I get a `Permission denied, please try again.` as an answer.

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ -z "${1}" ]] && OUT_FILE="WhereTheAnswearIsGoing.txt" || OUT_FILE="$1"
[[ -z "${2}" ]] && IN_FILE="Hosts.txt" || IN_FILE="$2"

while IFS= read -r host; do
        indication="$(sshpass -pfootbar ssh -p 2222 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -n "$host" 'who -b' | awk '{print $(NF-1)" "$NF}')"
        printf '%-14s %s\n' "$indication" "$host" >> "$OUT_FILE"
done < "$IN_FILE"
```

Sorry if this question is unclear but I don't know much about things like these.

Comment: What *exactly* is the error output you're receiving? Why is there a dot in your shebang line? Why does your script end with `~`? What's the (or a sample) input and what output do you expect? Please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: if you are getting "permission denied", your script probably lacks execute permission (run `chmod u+x name_of_script`). But indeed it is unclear what the script is trying to do, and hopefully there is a better way of doing it without writing passwords in plain text in any file.

Comment: "but I don't know much about things like these" - If you wrote or changed the script then you better should. Else [bad things may happen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming), as this is security sensitive code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks the message *`Permission denied, please try again.`* is generated by the SSH client. The password should be quoted to escape the special meaning of characters as `$`, `!`, etc. ([ref](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/982438/4)):

```
sshpass -p 'footbar' ...
```

Or you can use a file where the password to be stored ([source](https://askubuntu.com/a/982438/566421)):

```
sshpass -f "/path/to/passwordfile" ...
```

---

[image]

---

However, I remember, this is a script from my **previous [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/979457/566421)** where I mentioned that: *"Note here is assumed there is `~/.ssh/config` file and additional parameters as `-p 2222` are not needed ([reference](https://askubuntu.com/a/914678/566421))."* What I meant was:

The better solution is to (1) setup Key based SSH authentication, (2) create `~/.ssh/config` file and (3) modify the script to work with this setup.

**1.** Setup Key based SSH authentication ([source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys)).

- Generating RSA Keys and **don't enter passphrase**:

  ```
    mkdir ~/.ssh
    chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096
    chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  ```
- Transfer Client Key to **each** Host (please [note](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=99785) the quote marks):

  ```
    ssh-copy-id "<username>@<host> -p <port_nr>"
  ```
- Now you should be able to connect to the server(s) without password:

  ```
    ssh <username>@<host> -p <port_nr>
  ```
- Once this works, you could disable the password authentication (that is less secure method) by editing the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` of each host machine in this way:

  ```
    #PasswordAuthentication yes
    PasswordAuthentication no
  ```

**2.** Create `~/.ssh/config` file. (Read also: [How do I add multiple machines with the same configuration to ~/.ssh/config?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/991523/how-do-i-add-a-lot-of-machines-to-ssh-config-easily))

- The content of the file `~/.ssh/config` could look as this (*`host-i`* is object of your choice):

  ```
    Host host-1
        HostName <domain-or-IP-address>
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
        User <username>
        Port 2222
        # other parameters...

    Host host-2
        HostName <domain-or-IP-address>
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
        User <username>
        Port 2222
        # other parameters...

    Host host-3...
  ```
- Change the file permissions:

  ```
    chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config
  ```
- Now you should be able to connect to each of these hosts by a command as:

  ```
    ssh host-1
  ```

**3.A.** You can keep using the above scrip with a little modification:

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ -z $1 ]] && OUT_FILE="WhereTheAnswearIsGoing.txt" || OUT_FILE="$1"
[[ -z $2 ]] && IN_FILE="Hosts.txt" || IN_FILE="$2"

while IFS= read -r host; do
        indication="$(ssh -n "$host" 'who -b' | awk '{print $(NF-1)" "$NF}')"
        printf '%-14s %s\n' "$indication" "$host" >> "$OUT_FILE"
done < "$IN_FILE"
```

In this case the `Hosts.txt` file should be:

```
host-1
host-2
host-3
```

**3.B.** Or you can modify the script in more general way:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Collect the user's input, and if it`s empty set the default values
[[ -z $1 ]] && OUT_FILE="WhereTheAnswearIsGoing.txt" || OUT_FILE="$1"
# Provide the list of the hosts as an array
HOSTS=("host-1" "host-2" "host-3")

for host in "${HOSTS[@]}"; do
    indication="$(ssh -n "$host" 'who -b' | awk '{print $(NF-1)" "$NF}')"
    printf '%-14s %s\n' "$host" "$indication" >> "$OUT_FILE"
done
```

Comment: Interestingly for me, a password like "blahblah$dd" did not work, but when I changed the quotes to single quotes, it did.

Comment: Hi, @ViaTech, by default the most shells threat sequences like `$dd` as variables, and expanding them before run the command or do an assignment. Because there is not defined a variable named `$dd` - it doesn't have a value - when the shell expands it your actual password become `blahblah`. The purpose of the single quotes is just that - to prevent variable like strings from expansion. Another way to suppers the meaning of any (single) special character (in this case $) is to escape it by a backslash:  `"blahblah\$dd"`.

Comment: thanks for the extra info on variable definitions in shells! Makes much more sense, I hadn't thought `$` would still need escaping since it seemed having it in a str would cover it.