# How do I add multiple machines with the same configuration to ~/.ssh/config?

Tags: command-line, ssh

say, my `~/.ssh/config` has some line:

```
Host machine1
      User user
      HostName machine1
      ProxyCommand  ssh server nc %h %p 2> /dev/null
```

and this works properly, but the problem is that I have lot of `machines`: `machine1, machine2, machine3, ...` so how can I set all of them without manually copy same kind of lines

Comment: `Host machine*` would work too, for common config where part of the name matches.

Comment: @BoristheSpider See the last sentence of my answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do that this way:

```
Host machine1 machine2 machine3
      User user
      ProxyCommand ssh server nc %h %p 2>/dev/null
```

You just need to list the hosts in the `Host` line, separated by whitespace, and you can omit `HostName` if it's not different from the name you gave in the `Host` line. See [Multiple similar entries in ssh config · U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/61655/246819).

To simplify it even more there are the wildcards `*` and `?` available with their usual meaning, so `Host machine?` would be evenly possible for your example.

Comment: +1 . . . or even use a `?` or `*` wildcard such as `machine?` as described in the `PATTERNS` section of `man ssh_config`

Comment: `machine*` does not work, there should be a briliant way like this, dont know how to do it

Comment: `HostName %h` is redundant, you don't need it if you're not going to change the hostname.

Comment: I tried `Host machine*
  User wangtao
  HostName machine*
  ProxyCommand  ssh server nc %h %p 2> /dev/null
` but not work

Comment: @K.Wanter SSH patterns don't understand ranges. You can use `deep??` or `deep*` instead. (Or `deep1? deep2? deep3?` to be specific.)

Comment: with `Host machine* User wangtao HostName machine* ProxyCommand ssh server nc %h %p 2> /dev/null ` prompts `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`

Comment: @dessert works!  :)

Comment: @K.Wanter since I wasn't heard [the first time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/991523/how-do-i-add-multiple-machines-with-the-same-configuration-to-ssh-config/991534#comment1598995_991527), `HostName %h` is useless. Just skip the `HostName` line.

Comment: Is it possible to split this over multiple lines? My config file is getting rather obese.

Comment: @Alexander `man ssh_config` says “separated by whitespace”, and the newline character by definition is a whitespace character, so yes, you should be able to use a linebreak as a delimiter between two hosts as well. I couldn’t try it, but I trust the manpage. :)

Answer (score 7):

If your hostnames fit a pattern, you can use SSH's patterns:

You can use patterns in `~/.ssh/config`. From [`man ssh_config`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man5/ssh_config.5.html):

```
PATTERNS
     A pattern consists of zero or more non-whitespace characters, ‘*’ (a
     wildcard that matches zero or more characters), or ‘?’ (a wildcard that
     matches exactly one character).  For example, to specify a set of
     declarations for any host in the “.co.uk” set of domains, the following
     pattern could be used:

           Host *.co.uk

     The following pattern would match any host in the 192.168.0.[0-9] network
     range:

           Host 192.168.0.?
```

So, if you want to proxy everything in `*.example.com`, then in your `~/.ssh/config`, put:

```
Host *.example.com
    User user
    ProxyCommand ssh server nc %h %p 2> /dev/null
```

Or, using `ssh`'s own options, you can avoid netcat:

```
Host *.example.com
    User user
    ProxyCommand ssh -qW %h:%p server
```

From [`man ssh`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/ssh.1.html):

```
-W host:port
     Requests that standard input and output on the client be
     forwarded to host on port over the secure channel.  Implies -N,
     -T, ExitOnForwardFailure and ClearAllForwardings.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Host machine*
      User user
      ProxyCommand  ssh server nc %h %p 2> /dev/null
```

yes, the Hostname is redundant.