# ssh-agent won't start (even with eval ` `)

Tags: server, ssh, ssh-agent

I'm pulling my hair out on an ssh-agent issue..

I run a VPS under Ubuntu 16.04 and I setup a private/public key to be able to pull code from my Bitbucket repo. I initialized the repo, it all seemed to work fine, and a couple of days later, when I try to pull again, it tells me that the key is not valid.

*ssh-add -l* says "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent." - so I figure I just have to restart the ssh-agent.. but I always end up getting the same "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent." message.

```
me@ip:~/.ssh$ eval `ssh-agent -s`
Agent pid 3820
me@ip:~/.ssh$ ssh-add -l
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

I've tried rebooting the machine and attempting again but that's no good.. I've run out of ideas from all the posts I've read so.. any suggestions?

Comment: I also couldn't managed to get `ssh-agent` work as it is expected. You could try to use `~/.ssh/config` file instead that, here in section 2. is presented a short example:  https://askubuntu.com/a/986245/566421

Comment: I actually already have a config for Bitbucket, but that my "get pull" doesn't seem to care much about that unfortunately..

Comment: I'm connecting to `github.com` by this definition `Host github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/git/id_rsa`...

Comment: I have something very similar for Bitbucket - and it did actually work when I initialized the repo - but I have no idea why this isn't taken into account now when I try to pull..

Answer (score 1):

I set up ssh keys today for github.

This invokation was successful: `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`

Work through [these](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/) short articles, they are very clear and concise

Comment: Ok, this line did work.. however it seems that the problem is not with the command use but with the ssh software :( working with not issue on PuTTY, but still getting the "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent." on SmarTTY.. Well.. back to PuTTY I guess!